# Disable java-script debugging of asp.net(MVC) Application on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

Can we disable java-script debugging of a project after hosting on IIS server, so user can not debug the java-script code with inspection.

Or can we hide our `.js` source files in browser?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to prevent the Developer Tools for your end users.
But a little solution , you can prevent right-click to inspect element.

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```